# Object Returning ID Null on Android Studio

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I tried to retrieve the document ID that is randomly generated by firebase. I want to retrieve a tasks based on its ID so if i need to delete a bunch of tasks, I can just select the task and delete. I have the below code where I am trying to retrieve the taskID from the TaskList class where the setters and getters have been initialized for the field so I can delete a particular task. However, when I run the code, it returns the following error :

```
   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.riseapp, PID: 2160
java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.2:147)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.2:103)
    at com.example.riseapp.ViewTask.deleteTasks(ViewTask.java:183)
    at com.example.riseapp.ViewTask$3.onClick(ViewTask.java:113)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25919)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6826)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

/// Function for deleting the task

```
  deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteTasks();
        }
    });
   }


    public void deleteTasks() {
    userId = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    TaskList taskList = new TaskList();
    taskId = taskList.getTaskID();
    taskID.setText(taskId);

    final Map<String, Object> myfields = new HashMap<>();

    myfields.remove("taskName");
    myfields.remove("startTime");
    myfields.remove("endTime");
    myfields.remove("taskDate");
    myfields.remove("notes");
    myfields.remove("priority");
    myfields.remove("energy");
    myfields.remove("taskTag");

    DocumentReference noteRef = fStore.collection("usersData").document(userId).collection("tasks").document(taskId);
    noteRef.set(myfields)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.d("tag", "Task Deleted Successfully");
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `userId` and `taskId` in your reference? Are you sure that no one of them is null?

Comment: @AlexMamo userId is the random id generated for a user through firestore and that's not null. taskId is the random id generated for a task that was entered by a particular user. not sure why taskid is returning null

Comment: Check for nullity before using it.

Comment: @AlexMamo i did not understand. could u elaborate. i am not sure why the object is returning a null

Comment: You should debug your app to see why it's null.

Comment: yes i did that, but it didnt clearly show me why it was null @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.2:147)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.document(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.2:103)
    at com.example.riseapp.ViewTask.deleteTasks(ViewTask.java:183)
```

Is telling you that you passed null to `document()` on line 183 of ViewTask.java.

You will have to debug your application to figure out why either `userId` or `taskId` are null.  I suspect that it's `taskId`, but we can't see what actually generates that value.

Comment: It is the taskId thats null, i am calling the object in this line : ` TaskList taskList = new TaskList();` and getting it and storing it in taskId = taskList.getTaskID(); Not sure why this is returning a null

Comment: You have some debugging to do, then.

Comment: I did and its been fixed. Thank yiu